# The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.facebook.com' on ASP .NET Application

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a trouble when using the facebook login button. I'm currently using OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient() authentication process but suddenly it stopped working properly.

When I click on the login button I can go to Facebook to enter my account (if needed) and it fails on the callback and [then this error pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnPzU.png).

My ExternalLoginCallback code its this

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { returnUrl = returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

        string fbId = "";
        string first_name = "";
        string last_name = "";
        string email = "";

        if (result.ExtraData.Keys.Contains("accesstoken"))
        {
            var client = new FacebookClient(result.ExtraData["accesstoken"]);

            dynamic me = client.Get("me", new { fields = "email" });

            Session["facebooktoken"] = result.ExtraData["accesstoken"];

            fbId = result.ExtraData["id"];

            email = me.email;
        }
        else
        {
            String[] full_name = result.ExtraData["name"].ToString().Split(' ');

            if (full_name[0] != null)
                first_name = full_name[0];

            if (full_name[1] != null)
                last_name = full_name[1];
        }

        if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
        {
            SetAuthCookie(email);
            SetEncryptedCookie(Configuration.UserCookie, email, Configuration.CookieLifeTime);

            if (Request.Cookies["isFromCheckOut"] != null)
            {
                SetCookie("isFromCheckOut", false, false);
                RemoveCookie("isFromCheckOut");
                return RedirectToAction("Cart", "Store");
            }
            if (returnUrl != null)
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Store");
        }


        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // If the current user is logged in add the new account
            OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, email);
            SetAuthCookie(email);
            SetEncryptedCookie(Configuration.UserCookie, email, Configuration.CookieLifeTime);
            UserService.LastSeenUpdate(email);
            if (Request.Cookies["isFromCheckOut"] != null)
            {
                SetCookie("isFromCheckOut", false, false);
                RemoveCookie("isFromCheckOut");
                return RedirectToAction("Cart", "Store");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Store");
        }
        else
        {
            // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
            string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
            ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel
            {
                Id = fbId,
                UserName = email,
                ExternalLoginData = loginData,
            });
        }
```

This error ONLY shows up when I test it on production and not while debugging.

Comment: Then I guess production have problem connecting to Facebook and I would suggest to contact what ever support you have for the server